# GrantType Implicit workflow for IdentityServer 4 using Mobile Browser

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

We are using Dotnet core MVC web application, which we run in mobile chrome browser. We also have IdentityServer 4. Is It possible to detect by  Identity Server that request has been sent by Mobile?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to check whether the request is coming from a mobile device is by checking the user agent sent with each request. The user agent can be found in `HttpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"]`.

Then compare the user agent with a list of mobile browsers . You can use library to parse the user agent , for example [this](https://github.com/wangkanai/Detection) and [this](https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-csharp) library which will help finding the request is from which device and which browser .

Answer (score 0):

When you are communicating with IdentityServer, there is always a *ClientId*, you can implement *IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator* and register it in startup.cs file.

```
public class MyValidator : IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator
{
    public Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)
    {
        //check context.Request.ClientId
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
//...
})
.AddResourceOwnerValidator<MyValidator>()
```